# How can I destroy a session form an Angular client side, with a php joomla server?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, session, joomla

I have a php-joomla server giving an Angular app a user session. When the user wishes to logout, I can make a GET request to the php server and ask the server to logout and destroy the session. Although I don't want to rely on just the request to logout the user, in the event that the connection may not be reliable. I thought I would be able to find the session in the client app through a cookie or in session / local storage. Although upon looking they seem to be completely empty of any data regarding the user session.

```
window.sessionStorage // => {length: 0}
window.localStorage // => {length: 0}
document.cookie.split(';') // => [""]
```

Methods Used in PHP-Joomla

```
// Sign In
$auth = & JAuthentication::getInstance();
$credentials = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
$response = $auth->authenticate($credentials, $options);

// Sign Out
$session - JFactory::getSession();
$session->destroy();
```

**How does the php-joomla server store it's session data in the client application and how can I destroy it from the client side?**

Comment: I think you want to set the session timeout value.  I don't think you can control that in the client's browser, but you may control it on your php-joomla server.  You set it in a server file and then it will dispose the session automatically.

Comment: It totally depends on the implementation of Auth service between the Joomla server and the Angular application. If you can give more implementation details then it will help to answer your question. Also, you can check the REST component for Joomla which may helpful to you to develop the rest server for angular. https://github.com/techjoomla/com_api